# PowerShell Form Data Output To JSON Format

Tags: powershell

The following GIF image is an example of a dialog written use the C# programming language, which contains four controls!

Now, I want to use PowerShell to achieve the same functionality, I made the following design (such as the first dialog in the GIF picture):

The first control, the ID name is Input

The second control, the ID name is MultipleSelect

The third control, the ID name is InlineRadioOption

The fourth control, the ID name is Checkbox

When I click the OK button, I want to output the values ​​of all the controls to a JSON format object, for example: $CustomDialogResults

Later, I can get the value of each control in the following way (such as the second message box in the GIF image):

```
$CustomDialogResults.Input
$CustomDialogResults.MultipleSelect
$CustomDialogResults.InlineRadioOption
$CustomDialogResults.Checkbox
```

I want to know how to express objects in JSON format?

[image]

```
function Show-dialog_psf {

    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
    [void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
    #endregion Import Assemblies

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Objects
    #----------------------------------------------
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    $form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
    $labelInlinRadios = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
    $panel1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption3 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption2 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton'
    $Checkbox = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
    $MultipleSelect = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox'
    $labelMultipleSelect = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
    $input = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
    $labelInput = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
    $buttonOK = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
    $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'
    #endregion Generated Form Objects

    #----------------------------------------------
    # User Generated Script
    #----------------------------------------------

    $form1_Load = {
        #TODO: Initialize Form Controls here

    }

    $buttonOK_Click = {
        $CustomDialogResults = @{
            #$CustomDialogResults.Input,
            #$CustomDialogResults.MultipleSelect,
            #$CustomDialogResults.InlineRadioOption,
            #$CustomDialogResults.Checkbox,

        }
        [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($CustomDialogResults, 'Title') # Casting the method to [void] suppresses the output. 
    }

    # --End User Generated Script--
    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Events
    #----------------------------------------------

    $Form_StateCorrection_Load=
    {
        #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
        $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
    }

    $Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
    {
        #Remove all event handlers from the controls
        try
        {
            $buttonOK.remove_Click($buttonOK_Click)
            $form1.remove_Load($form1_Load)
            $form1.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
            $form1.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
        }
        catch { Out-Null <# Prevent PSScriptAnalyzer warning #> }
    }
    #endregion Generated Events

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Code
    #----------------------------------------------
    $form1.SuspendLayout()
    $panel1.SuspendLayout()
    #
    # form1
    #
    $form1.Controls.Add($labelInlinRadios)
    $form1.Controls.Add($panel1)
    $form1.Controls.Add($Checkbox)
    $form1.Controls.Add($MultipleSelect)
    $form1.Controls.Add($labelMultipleSelect)
    $form1.Controls.Add($input)
    $form1.Controls.Add($labelInput)
    $form1.Controls.Add($buttonOK)
    $form1.AcceptButton = $buttonOK
    $form1.AutoScaleDimensions = '6, 13'
    $form1.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
    $form1.ClientSize = '436, 288'
    $form1.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
    $form1.MaximizeBox = $False
    $form1.MinimizeBox = $False
    $form1.Name = 'form1'
    $form1.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
    $form1.Text = 'Form'
    $form1.add_Load($form1_Load)
    #
    # labelInlinRadios
    #
    $labelInlinRadios.AutoSize = $True
    $labelInlinRadios.Location = '21, 172'
    $labelInlinRadios.Name = 'labelInlinRadios'
    $labelInlinRadios.Size = '63, 17'
    $labelInlinRadios.TabIndex = 10
    $labelInlinRadios.Text = 'Inlin Radios'
    $labelInlinRadios.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    #
    # panel1
    #
    $panel1.Controls.Add($radiobuttonRadioOption3)
    $panel1.Controls.Add($radiobuttonRadioOption1)
    $panel1.Controls.Add($radiobuttonRadioOption2)
    $panel1.AutoSize = $True
    $panel1.Location = '95, 162'
    $panel1.Name = 'panel1'
    $panel1.Size = '329, 32'
    $panel1.TabIndex = 9
    #
    # radiobuttonRadioOption3
    #
    $radiobuttonRadioOption3.Location = '217, 5'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption3.Name = 'radiobuttonRadioOption3'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption3.Size = '105, 24'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption3.TabIndex = 7
    $radiobuttonRadioOption3.TabStop = $True
    $radiobuttonRadioOption3.Text = 'Radio option3'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption3.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    $radiobuttonRadioOption3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    #
    # radiobuttonRadioOption1
    #
    $radiobuttonRadioOption1.Location = '7, 4'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption1.Name = 'radiobuttonRadioOption1'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption1.Size = '105, 24'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption1.TabIndex = 5
    $radiobuttonRadioOption1.TabStop = $True
    $radiobuttonRadioOption1.Text = 'Radio option1'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption1.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    $radiobuttonRadioOption1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    #
    # radiobuttonRadioOption2
    #
    $radiobuttonRadioOption2.Location = '112, 4'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption2.Name = 'radiobuttonRadioOption2'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption2.Size = '105, 24'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption2.TabIndex = 6
    $radiobuttonRadioOption2.TabStop = $True
    $radiobuttonRadioOption2.Text = 'Radio option2'
    $radiobuttonRadioOption2.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    $radiobuttonRadioOption2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    #
    # Checkbox
    #
    $Checkbox.Location = '102, 200'
    $Checkbox.Name = 'Checkbox'
    $Checkbox.Size = '104, 24'
    $Checkbox.TabIndex = 8
    $Checkbox.Text = 'checkbox1'
    $Checkbox.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    $Checkbox.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    #
    # MultipleSelect
    #
    $MultipleSelect.CheckOnClick = $True
    $MultipleSelect.FormattingEnabled = $True
    [void]$MultipleSelect.Items.Add('Multiple Select option1')
    [void]$MultipleSelect.Items.Add('Multiple Select option2')
    [void]$MultipleSelect.Items.Add('Multiple Select option3')
    $MultipleSelect.Location = '121, 68'
    $MultipleSelect.Name = 'MultipleSelect'
    $MultipleSelect.Size = '277, 79'
    $MultipleSelect.TabIndex = 4
    $MultipleSelect.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    #
    # labelMultipleSelect
    #
    $labelMultipleSelect.AutoSize = $True
    $labelMultipleSelect.Location = '27, 68'
    $labelMultipleSelect.Name = 'labelMultipleSelect'
    $labelMultipleSelect.Size = '78, 17'
    $labelMultipleSelect.TabIndex = 3
    $labelMultipleSelect.Text = 'Multiple Select'
    $labelMultipleSelect.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    #
    # input
    #
    $input.Location = '121, 31'
    $input.Name = 'input'
    $input.Size = '277, 20'
    $input.TabIndex = 2
    $input.Text = 'input text'
    #
    # labelInput
    #
    $labelInput.AutoSize = $True
    $labelInput.Location = '76, 34'
    $labelInput.Name = 'labelInput'
    $labelInput.Size = '29, 17'
    $labelInput.TabIndex = 1
    $labelInput.Text = 'Input'
    $labelInput.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    #
    # buttonOK
    #
    $buttonOK.Anchor = 'Bottom, Right'
    $buttonOK.DialogResult = 'OK'
    $buttonOK.Location = '349, 253'
    $buttonOK.Name = 'buttonOK'
    $buttonOK.Size = '75, 23'
    $buttonOK.TabIndex = 0
    $buttonOK.Text = '&OK'
    $buttonOK.UseCompatibleTextRendering = $True
    $buttonOK.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $buttonOK.add_Click($buttonOK_Click)
    $panel1.ResumeLayout()
    $form1.ResumeLayout()
    #endregion Generated Form Code

    #----------------------------------------------

    #Save the initial state of the form
    $InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
    #Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
    $form1.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
    #Clean up the control events
    $form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    #Show the Form
    return $form1.ShowDialog()

} #End Function

#Call the form
Show-dialog_psf | Out-Null
```

Comment: Does `$CustomDialogResults |  ConvertTo-Json` help?

Comment: I don't know how to save the values ​​of all controls to variable $CustomDialogResults.

Comment: I thought you said the values are already members of the `$CustomDialogResults` object. Did you examine the output of `ConvertTo-Json`?

Comment: I only create the GUI interface now, I haven't added logic yet, the code is a bit long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your buttonOk click function to get desire output :

Note : This is the sample json, you have yo replace the hard-coded string with your actual values | objects.

> ```
>     $buttonOK_Click = {
>
>     $CustomDialogResults = @{}
>     $CustomDialogResults.Add("Input",$txtinput.Text)       
>     $CustomDialogResults.Add("MultipleSelect",$MultipleSelect.CheckedItems)
>
>     $CustomDialogResults.Add("Checkbox", $Checkbox.Checked)
>     $selectedradio = $null ;
>     switch($True)
>     {
>         $($radiobuttonRadioOption1.Checked){
>             $selectedradio = $radiobuttonRadioOption1.Text ;
>         } 
>         $($radiobuttonRadioOption2.Checked){
>             $selectedradio = $radiobuttonRadioOption2.Text ;
>         } 
>         $($radiobuttonRadioOption3.Checked){
>             $selectedradio = $radiobuttonRadioOption3.Text ;
>         }  
>     }
>
>     $CustomDialogResults.Add("InlineRadioOption",$selectedradio)
>     $temp = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $CustomDialogResults 
>     [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($temp, 'Title')  
> }
> ```

[image: sample Output]

Comment: I can't get the correct value using the code below, 

$CustomDialogResults.Add("Input",$($input.Text))

In addition, I don't understand the function of Get-RadioButtonCheck, Can you provide an example?

$CustomDialogResults.Add("InlineRadioOption",Get-RadioButtonCheck)

Comment: remove your cleanup event function and bindings

Comment: A little weird, I didn't set the binding

Comment: event binding when form closed.. try after removing that

Comment: The problem has been solved, the variable name, can not use input, I changed to input_ to succeed, thank you for your help

Comment: I just found a problem if I type Text\ in the input box, but it will become Text\\ in the JSON result.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this in ur ButtonOk_click eventhandler.

```
function Get-RadioButtonCheck
{
    #if-else logic
    #returns which Radio button is checked
    $CheckedRadioButton = "RadioButton1" #as an example
    Return $CheckedRadioButton
}

$CustomDialogResults = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Input = $($input.Text)
        MultipleSelect = $($MultipleSelect.SelectedItems)
        InlineRadioOption = Get-RadioButtonCheck
        Checkbox = $($Checkbox.Checked)
    }

$JSONdata = $CustomDialogResults | ConvertTo-Json
#Now you can output this $JSONdata to a file or text box or even a Messagebox like u are already doing
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, creating a custom object is also a solution